# Proof that abelian group $G$ implies, that $\text{ord}(gh)\mid \text{lcm}(\text{ord}(g),\text{ord}(h))$ for $g,h\in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I just took an exam in group theory, and one of the exercises asked for a proof for the following statement:

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $g,h\in G$ have $\text{ord}(g)=m$ and $\text{ord}(h)=n$. Assume $G$ is abelian. Then $\text{ord}(gh)\mid  \text{lcm}(m,n)$.

Any good suggestions on how this could have been answered?

Comment: Hint: $(gh)^{\mbox{lcm}(m,n)}=?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition $m,n\mid\text{lcm}(m,n)$, so we may write

- $\text{lcm}(m,n)=mr$
- $\text{lcm}(m,n)=ns$

Then compute

$$(gh)^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}=g^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}h^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}\\g^{mr}h^{ns}=(g^m)^r(h^n)^s\\e^re^s=e$$ Since $\text{ord}(gh)\leq\text{lcm}(m,n)$, we must have $\text{ord}(gh)\mid\text{lcm}(m,n)$.

Comment: I see. But where in this proof do we use that `G` is abelian?

Comment: @KristianS.Jensen $G$ being abelian gives you the first equality $$(gh)^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}=g^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}h^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}$$ this is not necessarily true for non-abelian groups, in which case you can only say that $(gh)^{\text{lcm}(m,n)}=(gh)(gh)\cdot\ldots\cdot (gh)$ tautologically.